# json_decode returning 1 when inside if condition

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
if(
    $jsonObj = json_decode($someJson) &&
    json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
) {

    print_r($jsonObj);
}
```

Output is `1`. Another way of writing it:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($someJson);

if(
    $jsonObj &&
    json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
) {

    print_r($jsonObj);
}
```

Output is a stdClass (what I want).

Why doesn't the first block of code work the same as the second? And maybe it would be fine to just write it like?:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($someJson);

if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {

    print_r($jsonObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
```

Means this:

```
$jsonObj = (json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)
```

Which is:

```
$jsonObj = ($somenonemptyvar && true)
```

So, `$jsonObj` is `true`.

You might want to use:

```
($jsonObj = json_decode($someJson)) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
```

And some reading: [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

You second suggestion would work fine though, *especially* if *falsy* values (0,`NULL`, false, empty array...) are a *valid* result for your `json_decode`.

Answer (score 7):

Because of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).  Boolean AND (`&&`) has higher precedence than assignment (`=`) so the first statement is effectively:

```
$jsonObj = (json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)
```

You'll need to add parentheses to get the outcome you want:

```
($jsonObj = json_decode($someJson)) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `=` has a lower priority with respect to logic operators:

```
if (
    $jsonObj = json_decode($someJson) &&
    json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
)
```

Is:

```
if ($jsonObj = json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)
```

Which groups as:

```
if ($jsonObj = (json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE))
```

So that this logical condition:

```
json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
```

Is first evalued (result `TRUE`, represented by `1`). Then, the result is assigned to `$jsonObj`, which becomes `1`. Finally, the `if` clause is evalued.

Your first version is actually equivalent to:

```
$jsonObj = (json_decode($someJson) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
if ($jsonObj) {
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if(
    $jsonObj = json_decode($someJson) &&
    json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE
) {
```

to

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($someJson);
if ($jsonObj && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE){
```

The `&&` is resolving before the `=` so you are assigning true